# installing mayavi with pip - Building TVTK classes...Assertion failed

Tags: python, mayavi

I've been trying to install mayavi in Yosemite. I've already installed the Numpy, VTK, wxPython, and configobj. When I run `sudo pip install mayavi`, it shows the following error msg:

```
Running setup.py install for mayavi
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Building TVTK classes...Assertion failed: ("pre: not_empty" && !IsEmpty()), function
GetAttributesToInterpolate, file /tmp/vtk-MvPwfE/VTK-6.1.0/Common/DataModel
/vtkGenericAttributeCollection.cxx, line 453.
    Complete output from command /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -c "import
setuptools,tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/mayavi/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-haj8cd-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
running build
```

I've no idea how to deal with this.

The following might be helpful.

```
{20:06:44}~/test ➭ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
{20:07:13}~/test ➭ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
{20:07:25}~/test ➭ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 19 2014, 06:00:59) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.56)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vtk
>>> vtk
<module 'vtk' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vtk/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I git cloned the mayavi, and run `python setup.py install`. It works.

Comment: good. Please accept your own answer so the question will not be considered unanswered.

Comment: @JonathanMarch Thanks. I can only accept my answer in 2 days. I'll do that then.

Answer (score 5):

I solved the same issue through pip with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/enthought/mayavi.git
```

Using this format, you can use pip to install from a particular git repo. Generally:

```
pip install git+(web address of git repo)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using the tar and pip from pypi. I downloaded the current zip file from Github and expanded it in a temporary directory. I had to run the 'python setup.py install' command twice for some reason before the install ran to completion. The mayavi module now works fine. I'm running on openSUSE 13.2.