# installing mayavi errors out with exit status -11

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, mayavi

On Fedora 31, I tried to install mayavi with pip

```
pip install mayavi
```

However, the following error occurs

```
  Building wheel for mayavi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -11:
   command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-ggg3s_hz
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/
  Complete output (55 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Building TVTK classes... vtkContextDevice2D: Ignoring method: Get/SetViewportRect
  default: [0, 0, 0, 0], range: None
  vtkContextDevice2D: Ignoring method: Get/SetViewportSize
  default: [0, 0], range: None
  vtkEventDataForDevice: Ignoring method: Get/SetAction
  default: -1, range: None
  vtkEventDataForDevice: Ignoring method: Get/SetDevice
  default: -1, range: None
  vtkFXAAOptions: Ignoring method: Get/SetDebugOptionValue
  default: 0, range: None
  vtkIncrementalForceLayout: Ignoring method: Get/SetGravityPoint
  default: [200.0, 200.0], range: None
  vtkOpenGLBufferObject: Ignoring method: Get/SetType
  default: 0, range: None
  vtkOpenGLFXAAFilter: Ignoring method: Get/SetDebugOptionValue
  default: 0, range: None
  vtkRenderWidget: Ignoring method: Get/SetPosition
  default: [0, 0], range: None
  vtkRenderWidget: Ignoring method: Get/SetSize
  default: [300, 300], range: None
  vtkShader: Ignoring method: Get/SetType
  default: 3, range: None
  vtkVolumeTexture: Ignoring method: Get/SetPartitions
  default: [1, 1, 1], range: None
  vtkChartMatrix: Ignoring method: Get/SetGutter
  default: [15.0, 15.0], range: None
  vtkChartMatrix: Ignoring method: Get/SetSize
  default: [0, 0], range: None
  vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetDrawAreaBounds
  default: [0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 300.0], range: None
  vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetDrawAreaResizeBehavior
  default: 0, range: None
  vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetFixedMargins
  default: [0, 0, 0, 0], range: None
  vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetFixedRect
  default: [0, 0, 300, 300], range: None
  vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetGeometry
  default: [0, 0, 300, 300], range: None
  vtkImplicitProjectOnPlaneDistance: Ignoring method: Get/SetNorm
  default: 2, range: None
  vtkOpenGLVertexBufferObject: Ignoring method: Get/SetCoordShiftAndScaleMethod
  default: 0, range: None
  vtkSimple3DCirclesStrategy: Ignoring method: Get/SetMarkedValue
  default: (invalid), range: None
  vtkArrayNorm: Ignoring method: Get/SetWindow
  default: [0, 9223372036854775807), range: None
  vtkChart: Ignoring method: Get/SetSize
  default: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], range: None
  vtkChartXYZ: Ignoring method: Get/SetAxisColor
  default: [0, 0, 0, 255], range: None
  Warning: We cannot determine the trait type of vtkHigherOrderHexahedron.Order
  Warning: We cannot determine the trait type of vtkHigherOrderQuadrilateral.Order
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mayavi
  Running setup.py clean for mayavi
Failed to build mayavi
Installing collected packages: mayavi
    Running setup.py install for mayavi ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -11:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-wln7h1zu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/imsantos/.local/include/python3.7m/mayavi
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/
    Complete output (55 lines):
    running install
    running build
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Building TVTK classes... vtkContextDevice2D: Ignoring method: Get/SetViewportRect
    default: [0, 0, 0, 0], range: None
    vtkContextDevice2D: Ignoring method: Get/SetViewportSize
    default: [0, 0], range: None
    vtkEventDataForDevice: Ignoring method: Get/SetAction
    default: -1, range: None
    vtkEventDataForDevice: Ignoring method: Get/SetDevice
    default: -1, range: None
    vtkFXAAOptions: Ignoring method: Get/SetDebugOptionValue
    default: 0, range: None
    vtkIncrementalForceLayout: Ignoring method: Get/SetGravityPoint
    default: [200.0, 200.0], range: None
    vtkOpenGLBufferObject: Ignoring method: Get/SetType
    default: 0, range: None
    vtkOpenGLFXAAFilter: Ignoring method: Get/SetDebugOptionValue
    default: 0, range: None
    vtkRenderWidget: Ignoring method: Get/SetPosition
    default: [0, 0], range: None
    vtkRenderWidget: Ignoring method: Get/SetSize
    default: [300, 300], range: None
    vtkShader: Ignoring method: Get/SetType
    default: 3, range: None
    vtkVolumeTexture: Ignoring method: Get/SetPartitions
    default: [1, 1, 1], range: None
    vtkChartMatrix: Ignoring method: Get/SetGutter
    default: [15.0, 15.0], range: None
    vtkChartMatrix: Ignoring method: Get/SetSize
    default: [0, 0], range: None
    vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetDrawAreaBounds
    default: [0.0, 0.0, 300.0, 300.0], range: None
    vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetDrawAreaResizeBehavior
    default: 0, range: None
    vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetFixedMargins
    default: [0, 0, 0, 0], range: None
    vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetFixedRect
    default: [0, 0, 300, 300], range: None
    vtkContextArea: Ignoring method: Get/SetGeometry
    default: [0, 0, 300, 300], range: None
    vtkImplicitProjectOnPlaneDistance: Ignoring method: Get/SetNorm
    default: 2, range: None
    vtkOpenGLVertexBufferObject: Ignoring method: Get/SetCoordShiftAndScaleMethod
    default: 0, range: None
    vtkSimple3DCirclesStrategy: Ignoring method: Get/SetMarkedValue
    default: (invalid), range: None
    vtkArrayNorm: Ignoring method: Get/SetWindow
    default: [0, 9223372036854775807), range: None
    vtkChart: Ignoring method: Get/SetSize
    default: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], range: None
    vtkChartXYZ: Ignoring method: Get/SetAxisColor
    default: [0, 0, 0, 255], range: None
    Warning: We cannot determine the trait type of vtkHigherOrderHexahedron.Order
    Warning: We cannot determine the trait type of vtkHigherOrderQuadrilateral.Order
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status -11: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4s7scony/mayavi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-wln7h1zu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/imsantos/.local/include/python3.7m/mayavi Check the logs for full command output.
```

Doing `python -c "import vtk"` doesn't raise an error. Same with `PyQt5`.

Running

```
import vtk
vtk.VTK_SOURCE_VERSION
```

indicates that I'm using vtk version 9.0.1.

`$PYTHONPATH` is empty.

Running as sudo doesn't change the error. I also tried `python3 -m pip install mayavi` with the same result.

How can I install mayavi with pip?

Comment: What version of vtk are you using?

Comment: @jakub vtk 9.0.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is the version of vtk that you are using. I had the same issue and the follwing worked for me:

`pip3 install vtk==8.1.2`

Note that this version of vtk is not available for version 3.8 and above of Python, so I'm not sure what the workaround is if you're using 3.8. I was using 3.7.

Then, try installing mayavi again.

`pip3 install mayavi`

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 20.04 as it stucks when using just 'pip install mayavi'. And I'm using Python 3.7 too.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue on Ubuntu 20.04. I was not able not able to install from pypi. I had to get the source and install via git:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/enthought/mayavi.git
```

There's a similar issue here [installing mayavi with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682120/installing-mayavi-with-pip-building-tvtk-classes-assertion-failed). The hint to the issue was the vtk traits.

For whatever reason, the vtk version can be found with:

```
import vtk
vtk.VTK_SOURCE_VERSION
```